# what is difference in using return before any function ex: "return Buy()" or "Buy()"

Tags: javascript

I have noticed one of my friend using this.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return Buy();">» <b class="font_bigger"><span id="buy_title">Buy</span> for <span class="points_in" id="buy_value">$1,691</span></b></a>
```

And i have feel no changed if i use this.

```
<a href="#" onclick="Buy();">» <b class="font_bigger"><span id="buy_title">Buy</span> for <span class="points_in" id="buy_value">$1,691</span></b></a>
```

So can any one explain what is the difference in both?

Just curious to know why he always use return.

Thanks

Comment: Notice that it's still possible to accomplish the same thing when only using `onclick="Buy();"` - inside of the `Buy` function, you can capture the event and call `preventDefault()` on it

Comment: thanks @ianpgall i figured it now :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first example a value will be returned from the `onclick` handler. This could be used to `return false` which would prevent the default behavior.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return Buy();">» <b class="font_bigger"><span id="buy_title">Buy</span> for <span class="points_in" id="buy_value">$1,691</span></b></a>
```

In the second example, the event handler will simply run, the event will propagate and the default behavior will execute regardless of any value returned by the event handler.

```
<a href="#" onclick="Buy();">» <b class="font_bigger"><span id="buy_title">Buy</span> for <span class="points_in" id="buy_value">$1,691</span></b></a>
```

Comment: Haha no problem. I was discussing this on some other question and the difference from jQuery was the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two actions involved here.

1. Default behavior: executing the `HREF`
2. Executing onClick event

**The events are executed first by the browser.** This behavior is called **`Early event handling`**. If the event action returns `false`, it prevents the default action i.e. `HREF`.

Comment: "Early event handling"? Never heard the term before in that context, so perhaps that's what **you** call that behaviour. Others just call it by its real name: the [DOM event model](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/).